# Apache 2.4.10 with VPS

Tags: apache, web-services

I have a 1GB ram Apache 2.4.10 (MPM event) VPS, my user complained that they always encounter broken webpage or image was loaded frquently, when I try to use fiddler to investigate, I found content length mismatch problem occurred in those broken image/pages. Seems that Apache sometimes did not sent the whole file to the client. I already disable HTTP/206 in Apache server but problem still persisted.

Any idea on it ? Or i need to install the newest version 2.4.16 ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to check your apache services error logs file so that you can find out the exact root cause of this issues. Please check that and let us know what error are you getting in error logs file ? We will try to help you on this with the that error logs.

Comment: I have looked for the error_log but there are nothing logged when I encountered the problem. :(